# Issue a custom command using pitunnel

Tags: python, remote, servo

I have a Pi 4 at home, which is wired in to some servos which, via a python script, make hands turn on a clock face, making them point to 'home', 'work', 'school' etc - I think you can see what this is going to end up being.

All the hardware is done, and I can easily pitunnel in, cd to the script directory, and run  `python3 set_hand.py 0 10`, which will set the first hand to 10 degrees.

Problem now is enabling remote access to do this. Is there any way to set up a persistent custom pitunnel which would wrap up such a procedure, ie, do the cd and run the script, when accessed via a protocol which something like a phone running IFTTT can manage? (I don't know for certain what IFTTT is capable of, it's just an example of an app which executes actions based on custom conditions).

Any other solution gratefully accepted. I'm hoping to avoid the need to do a custom flask project, set up a webserver etc.

Comment: Can IFTTT run SSH commands? Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification.